# How to add delay to Javascript video play trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sequence of videos that I want to loop through seamlessly by clicking on them, giving the appearance of an interactive animation.

I've managed to get the videos to hide/show on click by using a Javascript counter to add and remove a css class on click, but in order to make the videos transition seamlessly between clicks I need them to play to the end before triggering the remove/add event.

How would I go about doing this? I have played around with adding a delay to the click event but so far nothing has worked.

Please check out this fiddle for clarity (clicking the hand video fast illustrates the problem best):
https://jsfiddle.net/62rf3mtw/19/

```
var hand1 = document.getElementById("hand1");
var hand2 = document.getElementById("hand2");
var hand3 = document.getElementById("hand3");
var hand4 = document.getElementById("hand4");

var handcount = 0
$(".hand").click(function() {
handcount++;
if(handcount == 1) {
    $(".hand1").addClass("hide");
    hand1.pause();
    hand1.currentTime = '0';

    $(".hand2").get(0).play();
    $(".hand2").removeClass("hide");
}else if(handcount == 2){
    $(".hand2").addClass("hide");
    hand2.pause();
    hand2.currentTime = '0';

    $(".hand3").get(0).play();
    $(".hand3").removeClass("hide");
}else if(handcount == 3){
    $(".hand3").addClass("hide");
    hand3.pause();
    hand3.currentTime = '0';

    $(".hand4").get(0).play();
    $(".hand4").removeClass("hide");
}else if(handcount == 4){
    $(".hand4").addClass("hide");
    hand4.pause();
    hand4.currentTime = '0';


    $(".hand1").get(0).play();
    $(".hand1").removeClass("hide");
    handcount = 0;
}    
})
```

Comment: do you really need to wait until the end before toggling? Your fiddle seems to work fine if you click fast through the clips

Answer (score 2):

By reading your code I found more than one issue that I will explain to you right now.

## Solving your question

The fact about @Ajay Kumar answer is kind of right, but not true. To detect when a video has done playing, you should use the `ended` property of the element in JavaScript. But make sure you are calling it from a `video tag` only, not from any other tag.

That is why, in the code I will explain you right after this, I used:

```js
if(currentEgg.ended){
   ...
}
```

To handle when the code to hide the current element and show the next one will be executed or not. Otherwise, your code will always execute even if the video hasn't ended yet.

***Note:** I will give you an example of how it works using only one element of your question, Eggs.*

---

## [You might not need jQuery.](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Why am I telling you this? Because most of the behavior of your code is handled by HTML5 standard. This means you don't really need jQuery to play the video or give any extra functionality to your code.

---

## Keep code clean, simple and readable.

By this I really mean a lot of things, which in fact I will **show** and also **prove** you what I mean with the example I will show you.

Let's say that you have your HTML like this:

```
<div class="eggs">
    <video class="egg" autoplay muted src="http://178.128.41.21/assets/imgs/egg/01_Monster/01_Monster_in.mp4?v=ce3e201d46" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <video class="hide egg" muted src="http://178.128.41.21/assets/imgs/egg/01_Monster/02_Monster_click_1.mp4?v=ce3e201d46" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <video class="hide egg" muted src="http://178.128.41.21/assets/imgs/egg/01_Monster/03_Monster_click_2.mp4?v=ce3e201d46" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <video class="hide egg" muted src="http://178.128.41.21/assets/imgs/egg/05_Meat/03_Meat_click_3.mp4?v=ce3e201d46" type="video/mp4"></video>
    <video class="hide egg" muted src="http://178.128.41.21/assets/imgs/egg/05_Meat/05_Meat_click_4.mp4?v=ce3e201d46" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>
```

I bet you can see how it looks a lot simpler with just two classes on it, `egg` and `hide`.

You might be questioning yourself: *"But, how am I going to make the animation then?"*. Well, take a look at the magic that JavaScript can do.

---

## Getting the code simple and functional.

I will now detail you how the same behavior can be done with cleaner and simpler code:

#### Retrieving all the video elements from the DOM

```js
var eggElements = document.querySelectorAll(".egg"),
    eggClick = document.querySelector(".eggs"),
    eggcount = 0;
```

Now we have every video tag in `eggElements` as an array, and our div that will handle the click event is in `eggClick`. Looks amazing, right? Take a look at the handler function.

#### Handling the clicks

```js
eggClick.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let currentEgg = eggElements[eggcount],
        nextEgg = (eggcount + 2 > eggElements.length ? eggElements[1] : eggElements[eggcount + 1])
    if (currentEgg.ended) {
        currentEgg.classList.add("hide");
        currentEgg.pause();
        currentEgg.currentTime = '0';
        nextEgg.play();
        nextEgg.classList.remove("hide");
        eggcount = (eggcount + 2 > eggElements.length ? 1 : eggcount + 1);
    }
});
```

With this, you can just get rid of those multiple if statements and shorten your code.

And to prove you this works, you can check it by yourself in this [LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/6u53ynxg/).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, this works great! One more thing that I realised that I missed adding in my initial post is that I also want to add a a mouse-on and mouse-off effect for some of the clips. These would also need to play their full length before any clicks can be done. Do you know of a good way to get this to work together with your code?

Thanks,
S

Comment: Glad to know that. Just change the event to listen to. Instead of `addEventListener("click" . . .` use `addEventListener("mouseover" . . .`.

Answer (score 0):

check for ended property of video

```
$(".hand").click(function(e) {
if (e.target.ended) {
    handcount++;
    if(handcount == 1) {
        $(".hand1").addClass("hide");
        hand1.pause();
        hand1.currentTime = '0';

        $(".hand2").get(0).play();
        $(".hand2").removeClass("hide");
    }else if(handcount == 2){
        $(".hand2").addClass("hide");
        hand2.pause();
        hand2.currentTime = '0';

        $(".hand3").get(0).play();
        $(".hand3").removeClass("hide");
    }else if(handcount == 3){
        $(".hand3").addClass("hide");
        hand3.pause();
        hand3.currentTime = '0';

        $(".hand4").get(0).play();
        $(".hand4").removeClass("hide");
    }else if(handcount == 4){
        $(".hand4").addClass("hide");
        hand4.pause();
        hand4.currentTime = '0';


        $(".hand1").get(0).play();
        $(".hand1").removeClass("hide");
        handcount = 0;
    } 
    }
})
```

Comment: There is no `ended` property for a div.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example with your code and combined `playing` with `onended` to get the result you wanted.

Read the comment to understand what's happening.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzpoukeL/1/) example.